Transaction is not displayed in transactions list
Today I intergrate paypal in my application. everything work fine, I can create order and then capture order, but when I fetch transactions list using postman and paypal api, this captured order(transaction) not present in this list. however. my balance change and also change my bousiness account balance. I use sandbox account not buiseness.
I try also create order using postman, but transaction not display.


I waited more when 4 hours


Wait longer, the sandbox is slow. And the transaction search API should not be used for anything important.

why? I want display all transactions, but I cant' find any other api fot this.

it is slow. record transaction info in your own database when payments are captured. use that info.

also I have one question about capture. I added webhooks for checkout.complete and payment.complete. when I capture order I receive payment.complete, why?

because that is the normal behavior and sufficient, if webhooks are even needed (they rarely are, better use the immediate capture API response)
